# Resize Canvas when viewport width/height is changed without having to refresh

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've set up a canvas set up based on a tutorial but I need to make it responsive. At the moment I can resize the canvas if I change the viewport size and refresh but I need it to do it in real time.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="" height=""></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 

canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize',() => {
    canvas.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
})

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Rectangles

c.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)"
c.fillRect(50, 100, 100, 100);
```

I've tried adding an EventListener but the console is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.setSize is not a function"

How would I get the EventListener to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
canvas.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
```

`canvas.setSize` is really not a thing, so that's why you're getting TypeError.